# How does Polyphonic playback in Godot game engine work?

Tags: audio, game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

While implementing polyphonic playback in Godot game engine according to the documentation provided I encounter a few errors:

1. The methods can only be called from the class `AudioStreamPlaybackPolyphonic` but calling from this class directly causes the error:

```
Cannot call non-static function "play_stream()" on the class "AudioStreamPlaybackPolyphonic" directly. Make an instance instead.
```

2. When creating an instance for the function to be called on using the following code:

```
func create_audio_instance(value, offset, volume, pitch):
    var instance = audio.instantiate()
    get_parent().add_child(instance)
    instance.play_stream(value, offset, volume, pitch)
    instance.queue_free()
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred.
Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'play_stream' in base 'Node (SFX.gd)'.
```

This makes sense as the function is located in the class `AudioStreamPlaybackPolyphonic`.

The file this code is located in `extends PolyInst` my custom class, this custom class `extends Node` as well as having a custom class named `phonics` that extends the class `AudioStreamPlaybackPolyphonic`.

Using direct inheritance doesn't work, and trying to create an instance of the function with or without the inheritance doesn't work.

Is there another way to call a function or create an instance of the class/function that I do not know about?

The minimum code needed to reproduce this follows.

`SFX.gd` file extending `SFX.tscn` with a `base Node` and one `AudioStreamPlayer2D`:

```
extends CustomClass

func play_sfx(value, offset, volume, pitch): 
    $SoundFX.stream = SFXArray[value]
    create_audio_instance(value, offset, volume, pitch) # Works to create instances and play the sound if using $SoundFX.play() but does not have polyphony. All sounds instanced will overide previous sounds.
    
func create_audio_instance(value, offset, volume, pitch):
    var instance = audio.instantiate()
    get_parent().add_child(instance)

    #$SoundFX.get_stream_playback()
    instance.play_stream(value, offset, volume, pitch)
    instance.queue_free()
```

`CustomClass.gd` file:

```
extends Node
class_name CustomClass

# Load Node for Instancing
const audio = preload("res://Autoloads/SFX.tscn")

# Asset Files
var testsound = load("res://your_file_here")

# SFX Storage Array
var SFXArray = [
    
    testsound, # 0

]

class phonics: extends AudioStreamPlaybackPolyphonic
```

Use the above code and mentioned setup and call the `play_sfx(0, 0, 0, 1)` function in your main scene to reproduce the errors.

I have attempted various different implementations of the code, all with the same effect.

The instances themselves work, polyphony does not.